# How to make Eclipse Formatter to not destroy commented out code?

Tags: eclipse, formatting

A lot of my co-workers enjoy leaving behind commented out code, how to make Eclipse Formatter to not destroy formatting of that code(now it makes a big blob or block of it).

P.S. I know I can somehow configure the formatter to just ignore that code, I done it once, but I cant remember how.

Comment: Leaving commented-out code checked in is bad practise. Delete the code instead, and your co-worker might stop doing it. ;-)

Comment: Sometimes having co-worker is a bad practise ;) however if you can't beat them - join them!

Comment: It is NOT bad practice to leave comment-out code.  It will get lost in the versions if it's something you intend to bring back.  I also comment out code that's "sample code" on how to run something.  And while developing a module, I comment out code that I may use again before I check things in.  (In my experience, the "don't do it", "It's bad practice" response is often a shortsighted response, or a preference)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the Eclipse Formatter Settings (Preferences/Java/Code Style/Formatter) in the tab Comments UNCHECK the checkbox "Enable Block Comment Formatting" and "Enable Line Comment Formatting" These should be disabled anyway.

Comment: For those using eclipse 4.20.0 (and above), create a new profile after navigating Preferences>Java>Code Style>Formatter and then follow above steps. Direct option of comments is not available hence create a new profile

Answer (score 6):

One option in 3.6 would be to [tell Eclipse not to format these blocks](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6-201006080911/eclipse-news-part2.html#JavaFormatter), using `/* @formatter:off */`

Another option that I use a lot when working in other people's code is to select the lines I'm working on before invoking the formatter - that way I only format the areas I've actually changed, and leave the rest untouched (to get more readable diffs etc.).

Comment: cool idea, however its not universal for me and I would have to look for commented out code before every formatting.

Answer (score 3):

For Eclipse 3.7.1, there's a new configuration page (Off/On Tags) in the code format profiles. Make sure you've enabled them. You can also specify the exact comment off and comment on tags.