# Eclipse formatter comment indentation

Tags: eclipse, indentation

I´ve been messing around with the auto formatter (default) from Eclipse 3.6
While configuring things I didn´t find a possibility to indent comments which comes after some code in a line. (Language is c)

e.g.

```
int example;                  //comment1
int another_example;          //comment2
```

when I´m using the auto formater it removes the indentation like this:

```
int example; //comment1
int another_example; //comment2
```

Is there a way to do so and not avoiding the formater to come in effect on those line?

Comment: These kind of things should be searched on google rather then asking here.

Comment: These questions may help you.

[Q1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820908/how-to-turn-off-the-eclipse-code-formatter-for-certain-sections-of-java-code) 
and 
[Q2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606699/how-to-make-eclipse-formatter-to-not-destroy-commented-out-code)

Comment: @user3007735 thx that helped a lot...I´ve already been looking for an answer, no win at all

Comment: @Foolish that´s what I found too, adding stuff to my comment, but rather then adding this (would be annoying with variable comments) I thought there must be a better way for this